# clearing radio input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of radio buttons that are below. These radio buttons are part of a larger form and are optional, so If a user clicks on one, then decides he/she doesn't want the option selected, there is no way to undo this.

I was wondering if there was any jQuery etc, that, when clicking a link for example, clear any radio selection, based on the `group` name in the HTML?

Thanks

Comment: Just have a "none of these" option in each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var group_name = "the_group_name";

// if jquery 1.6++
$(":radio[name='" + group_name + "']").prop('checked', false);

// prev than 1.6
// $(":radio[name='" + group_name + "']").attr('checked', false);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/66FYL/

Comment: Looking at the JS you provided on jsfiddle all seems to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var Custom = {
init: function() {
checkAllPrettyCheckboxes = function(caller, container){

        // Find the label corresponding to each checkbox and click it
        $(container).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function(){

            if($.browser.msie){
                $(this).attr('checked','checked');
            }else{
                $(this).trigger('click');
            };
        });
        };

        uncheckAllPrettyCheckboxes = function(caller, container){

            // Find the label corresponding to each checkbox and unselect them
            $(container).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
                $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').trigger('click');
                if($.browser.msie){
                    $(this).attr('checked','');
                }else{
                    $(this).trigger('click');
                };
            });
        };
```

I have created it in an init function, and adter then i called the init. 
}
    window.onload = Custom.init;

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution like **roberkules**' solution, except mine clears the radiobutton if you **click the radiobutton itself** while it's checked. Use this if you don't want to add an extra "Clear" button to your layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/P9zZQ/6/

```
// Requires JQuery 1.4+ (possibly earlier)

$(function () {
    // Turn off a radiobutton if clicked again while on
    var checkOff = function (event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        if (target.is('label')) {
            // deal with clicked label
            if (target.attr('for')) {
                // label has 'for' attribute
                target = $('#' + target.attr('for'));
            } else {
                // label contains a radiobutton as a child
                target = target.find('input[type=radio]');
            }
        }
        if (target.is('input:checked[type=radio]')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                target.attr('checked', false);
            }, 200);
        }
    }

    // Find all radiobuttons and labels inside .radio-clearable containers
    $(
        '.radio-clearable input[type=radio], ' +
        '.radio-clearable label').mousedown(function (event) {
        // When clicked -- clear if it was checked
        checkOff(event);
    }).keydown(function (event) {
        // When receiving space, escape, enter, del, or bksp -- clear if it was checked
        if (event.which == 32 || event.which == 27 || event.which == 13 || which == 46 || which == 8) {
            checkOff(event);
        }
    });
});
```

Usage: For any radiobutton you want to be clearable in this manner, wrap it in a container with class "radio-clearable".

The code is triggered by clicking or sending a key (Space, Escape, Enter, Del, BkSp) to the radiobutton element or to its label.